# How to switch off solution wide analysis in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

On the PC of my collegue Visual Studio 2015 displays a message sometimes:

> Low memory detected. Solution wide analysis is switched off.

And after this message is displayed everything is a lot faster.

How can I turn this analysis off manually?

**Edit:** 
Yes, I use Resharper but this is not what I want. And Code Analysis is also not the correct option. VS 2015 uses Roslyn to compile the Solution constantly in the background and uses all kinds of Analysers, almost like Resharper. But I use Resharper so I would like to turn off all background checks of Roslyn.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? I believe this is a ReSharper setting, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable full solution analysis in Visual Studio 2015, go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced, and uncheck the "Enable full solution analysis" checkbox.

Note that after installing [the latest version of VS2015 Update 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx), this settings is now disabled by default.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure if this option is the one I'm looking for. because I have switched this off and still sometimes get this yellow 'low memory detected - solution wide analysis switched off.' warning...???

Comment: OK, according to this https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Performance-considerations-for-large-solutions the option is supposed to disable solution wide analysis. The article is describing also some other performance tweaks...

Answer (score 1):

To enable or disable automatic code analysis
In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and then click Properties.
In the properties dialog box for the project, click Code Analysis.
Specify the build type in Configuration and the target platform in Platform.
To enable or disable automatic code analysis, select or clear the Enable Code Analysis on Build (defines CODE_ANALYSIS constant) check box.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx)

Comment: "Solution wide analysis" or "full solution analysis" is a new feature in VS2015. It's separate from "Code Analysis".